# Installing Passenger & Nginx using Vagrant shell script

Tags: shell, nginx, vagrant, passenger

This is my first post to SO so I hope I'm asking this correctly.

I wrote a shell script to automate the installation of Passenger & Nginx (along with some other components) without any user input on a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 14.04.  It works fine using the following:

```
echo "****** Adding Passenger & Nginx Repo ******"
    sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
    sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates -y
    echo "deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
    sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
    sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
    sudo apt-get update
echo "****** Installing Passenger & Nginx ******"
    sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger -y
```

Now I want to do the same thing for a Vagrant VM running CentOS 6.4. I followed the directions for CentOS found on the [Phusion Passenger site](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html) but I can't seem to get it working properly.  When I do the following, the output from the shell script says "No package passenger available.":

```
echo "****** Adding Passenger & Nginx Repo ******"
    sudo yum install epel-release pygpgme curl -y
    sudo 'echo "curl --fail -sSLo /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/definitions/el-passenger.repo"'
    sudo chown root: /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo
    sudo chmod 600 /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo
    sudo yum update
echo "****** Installing Passenger & Nginx ******"
    sudo yum install nginx passenger -y
```

Looking in the /etc/yum.repos.d directory after the script is run, there is no passenger.repo listed, so it looks like for whatever reason curl is not downloading the repo file.  However, if I manually type the commands in my terminal command line after the script finishes it will pull down the repo and run.

I'm probably doing something stupid here, but I'm rather new to shell scripting and can't seem to figure out where the problem is.

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sudo 'echo "curl --fail -sSLo /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/definitions/el-passenger.repo"'

That is wrong and is not what the manual instructed. It should be:

```
sudo curl --fail -sSLo /etc/yum.repos.d/passenger.repo https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/yum/definitions/el-passenger.repo
```

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I thought since I was in a shell environment I would need to issue an echo first, but it still downloaded the passenger.repo file even without the echo.  Thanks for your help.